# Animating alterations to DEM based on function using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, raster-calculator, arcscene, animation

I've generated a function that alters height values of a DEM based on certain criteria. What I'm looking at doing now is animating this in ArcScene. Is there a way, in ArcGIS, for each frame to be the result of a raster calculation?

eg Frame_Timecode-->(function)-->Adjusted_DEM-->render

I'm a strong Python programmer, but have not yet done any scripting with ArcGIS, so I'm quite happy if the answer involves some coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was unable to find a way of making ArcScene conform to my desires here.

I've instead opted to [convert the DEM to a NumPy array](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//03q300000029000000) and do the animation using MatPlotLib's [surface_plot](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots).

A bit more setup required, but FAR more flexibility!